# Composite clustered PK behavior vs Nonclustered PK + nonunique clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have a table with a few columns, the 2 important ones are appid and fileid. Together, they make up a PK for the table. A typical use case for the table will be how many files contain appid x, or which appid is the most popular. Those queries will be run very often on only subsets of files as well, instead of all files. Neither column is unique individually.

Based on that, I feel like the best choice for a clustered index would be AppId. However, since setting both columns as a PK will make an extra nonclustered index, and appids lack of uniqueness (there will be lots of repeats) means it will need a uniquifier column behind the scenes anyway, would it make more sense to just say the PK is clustered and not specify another clustered index? Assuming I specified AppId first in the PK, would it treat diagnosticfileid like a uniquifier behind the scenes and give me the optimal performance that way?

EDIT: An important thing i forgot to originally mention is that APPId's won't be steadily increasing or anything, so there will be insertions to the middle of the table. I was thinking I could prevent some problems with this by using a fillfactor, but the table will get pretty big, so I dont know how much that will help.

Also, it is going to be inserted into pretty often, but never large chunks at a time. Probably something like a few thousand rows an hour. There isn't really any value that will reliably increase and be a good choice for a clustered index in that respect, but I wasn't sure how big of a deal that is. I could add an id just to have a good value to cluster around, but I feel like that'd slow down selects a lot.

Comment: how is the "most popular `appId`" defined? is it the one with most files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your two most popular queries are "how many files contain `appId`" and "which `appId` is most popular", you should make this indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW
        v_appCount
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
        SELECT  appId, COUNT_BIG(*) AS cnt
        FROM    dbo.mytable
        GROUP BY
                appId
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
        ux_v_appCount_appId
ON      v_appCount (appId)
```

This way you could run those queries:

```
SELECT  cnt
FROM    v_appCount
WHERE   appId = @myAppId
```

and

```
SELECT  TOP 100
        *
FROM    v_appCount va
ORDER BY
        appId DESC
```

almost instantly.

Comment: and then should I just make my table a heap? or have a clustered index on it?

Comment: @bdwain If you ask that question, make it clustered. You're probably not experienced enough to deal with all the consequences of choosing a heap. It has subtle drawbacks.

Comment: But the view refers to the table? So the indexing on it would matter, won't it?

Comment: So wouldn't the indexes have an effect on the time it takes to update the view when I update the table? Also, how can the table not be looked into without storing all of the data?

Comment: I'm just trying to better understand how this will help. I will still need to access the data in ways this view won't be designed for, so I want to have a good indexing scheme on the original table. 

And no I haven't had peformance problems yet I'm still in the design phase.

Comment: So are you saying any of the following options are good for the original table? add an identity PK  and make it the clustered index. Add a clustered index on AppId and make the PK a nonclustered composite index on fileid and appid. Add a clustered composite pk on appid and fileid. but NOT no clustered index.

Comment: The other queries are less common and involve other tables and are too complicated to explain here. But do you think I should optimize the table for those queries and just optimize the view for the appid ones?

Comment: one other common query is bascially how many files in a certain subset of all files have this appid. Would that require a different clustered view?

Comment: so is a view bascially a queryable index?

Comment: The problem I see with doing a composite PK is that the value would cause lots of page splits. The only way I could avoid page splits and have a clustered index is to add an identity column which won't be used. From my discussion with Nick below, I feel like in that case a heap wouldn't be a "wrong" choice because there would be no advantage to a clustered identity column (even if the drawbacks are negligible) and any other clustered index would degrade insert performance a lot, whicH I don't want to do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28432/discussion-between-quassnoi-and-bdwain)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with compound PKs comes if they are clustered, because an insert in the middle of the table causes a physical reordering of the contents.  If the table is not expected to reach ginormous sizes, then it probably won't matter, but it is definitely something to consider.  I should add that if this is a high select table and a low insert table, then that also limits the impact of inserts in the middle of the primary key.  You could definitely make it a non-clustered primary key, but that has select performance considerations.

**EDIT**
Considering your edit, I would recommend you do an auto incrementing PK (that is nonclustered) and create a unique constraint (which also creates a unique, non-clustered index).  Basically, I wouldn't recommend a clustered index on this table.  I don't think you'll see much performance difference without it, but you would if it were there and you did thousands of inserts in the middle of a table.  Deadlocks will haunt you.

Take a quick read at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).  While it is old, the principles still apply.

Comment: I agree with the "stuff it in there" issue with the compound PK that is clustered.  Be careful.....

Comment: i added some info to the original post that I forgot to add originally. Let me know if that makes the right choice a little more obvious.

Comment: I don't see the point in adding a nonclustered id PK. If I ever wanted to access the table by that id, wouldn't it would be better to be clustered? And if I never wanted to access it by the id, then an extra nonclustered index that I never search with seems useless. I could just have the PK be the composite unique constraint. The only benefit I can see of an auto incrementing PK is that I could cluster on it easily.

Comment: Excluding the identity column is fine.  When I design tables, I opt to include it because there may be some point in the future where I want to reference it.  But you're right, it is not necessary and may very well be a waste of space in your case.

Comment: Inserts into the middle cause page splits not a reordering of the whole table. Page splits alao occur for inserts into the middle of a non clustered index.

Comment: so you don't think it makes sense to have a clustered identity column? How much overhead is that when inserting vs no clustered index. I guess it adds an int to each row, but besides space concerns, is there much of a downside?

Comment: If you're asking me, I'd put it in because the overhead is negligible, but no one would say you did it wrong if you didn't include it.

Comment: To be clear, the only benefit of including a clustered identity column over no clustered index would be if i wanted to search by that identity later right?

Comment: I would make the identity column non-clustered, but yes, the only benefit would be to be able to foreign key to that single column and/or search for that row by that column value.

Comment: Back to my comment from from before. Assuming an identity was a good choice because I wanted to make an FK to it or something, what benefit is there in making the identity nonclustered (and having no clustered index) over clustered? It's not going to cause page splits, and will be faster to look up by the id if it's clustered.

Comment: I think @Quassnoi has the best approach.  I wouldn't worry too much about the identity column.  But, refer to the comment by Martin regarding page splits.